# Elixir anonymous function as a function parameter

Tags: elixir

Trying to pass a custom function to the following function but I have no luck.

```
   defmodule M do
     def custom_fn([head|tail],fnce) do
        fnce.(head)
        custom_fn(tail,fnce)
      end

     def custom_fn([]), do: nil

   end
```

Trying to call it like this:

```
M.custom_fn([1,2,3], (fn(x) -> x * 10 end))
```

Getting this

```
** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in M.custom_fn/2    

The following arguments were given to M.custom_fn/2:

    # 1
    []

    # 2
    #Function<6.99386804/1 in :erl_eval.expr/5>

test.ex:11: M.custom_fn/2
```

Also, what does the following message say? M.custom_fn/2
To be more specific, I don't understand **/2**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/2` is a [function arity](https://elixir-lang.org/crash-course.html#modules).

The issue is not with a function at all.

```rb
def custom_fn([head|tail],fnce) do
  fnce.(head)
  # ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ HERE
  custom_fn(tail,fnce)
end
```

The last call on an empty array is not matched. You should update the second clause to accept the second argument:

```rb
def custom_fn([], _), do: nil
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add the second argument to the base case. Like the error says, now you don't have any clause that matches `([], <function>)`.

```
def custom_fn([]), do: nil
```

should be

```
def custom_fn([], _), do: nil
```

Answer (score 2):

As other answers gives the explanation, I will give the right version.

```
defmodule M do
  def custom_fn([], _), do: nil
  def custom_fn([head|tail],fnce) do
    fnce.(head)
    custom_fn(tail,fnce)
  end
end

IO.inspect M.custom_fn([1,2,3], (fn(x) -> x * 10 end))
```

Comment: And make sure the function heads are in the order in which YongHao gives them.  Order is important on that particular construct.

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci no, in this particular case the order in **not** important. `[]` and `[h|t]` are never matched simultaneously. Otherwise OP would experience infinite recursion instead of match error.

Comment: Thanks for the correction; I'm just accustomed to order of function heads being important in general so I assumed it'd matter here too.